# How to close a bootstrap modal using the click event loaded from iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, iframe

I have loaded a url in iframe inside a bootstrap modal, I am trying to closemodal box using the class name which is loaded from  the iframe url.

here is my jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/fxfbzn7L/1/

and my code goes here

```
$('#terms_con').click(function () {
            $('#termsCondition').modal({
                show: true
            });
        });



         $('#termsCondition .btn-close').click(function () {
             $("#termsCondition").modal("hide");
            });
```

Comment: I don't see anything with a class name 'btn-close'

Comment: just click the modal popup and inspect the close text in popup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a false div on the `iframe` close button and add and event listener on the `div` to close the window. refer [this](https://jsfiddle.net/thinker3197/j9eq52jc/1/).